# Google OAuth2 login with youtube scope

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth, scopes, youtube-data-api

I am using google's OAuth2 login system (php library) and I want to get user's real email address as well as details for his youtube channel (with his permission).
I have tried using the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
```

but the returned email address has the format: @pages.plusgoogle.com (which is not the real email address).

If I use only the two scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

I am able to get the real address but I cannot access any youtube data.

I have also tried to use two different requests to google api. The first to grab the user info and a second one to get youtube related details. In this case the problem is that I do not have a unique key value to identify the user as the same person on my side (an ID or something to identify a user uniquely).

I believe my problem is related to this question:
[Google OAuth2 Login - Get YouTube nickname and real email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447149/google-oauth2-login-get-youtube-nickname-and-real-email-address/)

Any help would be appreciated.